# Jasper Report Error encountered when compiling report expected ;

Tags: jasper-reports

I am getting error when using sub report in jasper report.
First there was an error of resource not found: subreport.jrxml
Then the second error was subreport was not showing in the master report.
Now there is a new error and i am unable to sort it out.
This is the stack trace of my error.

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" 
>   "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
>   2019.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=38754:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\out\production\Medicare;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\fontawesomefx-8.9.jar;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\mysql-connector.jar;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\lib\Refined
>   Libs\commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\lib\Refined
>   Libs\commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\lib\Refined
>   Libs\commons-digester-2.1.jar;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\lib\Refined
>   Libs\commons-logging-1.1.1-1.0.0.jar;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\lib\Refined
>   Libs\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\lib\Refined
>   Libs\groovy-all-2.0.1.jar;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\lib\Refined
>   Libs\itext-2.1.7.js2.jar;C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\lib\Refined Libs\jasperreports-5.6.0.jar" model.Main Exception
>   in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)  at
>   javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)    at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)     ...
>   48 more Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors
>   were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
>   C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\Invoice_1582493155805_798440.java:246: error: ';' expected
>                   value = ((java.util.ArrayList)parameter_listOfItems.getValue())];
>   //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$
>                                                                                  ^ C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\Invoice_1582493155805_798440.java:364: error: ';' expected
>                   value = ((java.util.ArrayList)parameter_listOfItems.getValue())];
>   //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$
>                                                                                  ^ C:\wamp64\www\GitKraken\distribution\experts-machines\JavaFX\Younas
>   Traders\Invoice_1582493155805_798440.java:482: error: ';' expected
>                   value = ((java.util.ArrayList)parameter_listOfItems.getValue())];
>   //$JR_EXPR_ID=19$
>                                                                                  ^ 3 errors
>
> at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:204)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:354)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:340)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:605)
>     at
>   controller.ViewPendingOrders.generateInvoice(ViewPendingOrders.java:123)
>     ... 58 more

**Master Jasper Report.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.11.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.11.0-0c4056ccaa4d25a5a8c45672d2f764ea3498bebb  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Invoice" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="4eedbb89-b4f6-4469-9ab6-f642a1688cf7">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#EEEFF0"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="Table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#CACED0">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#D8D8D8"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="tableDataset" uuid="f13e6d36-5148-4ecc-bbe3-3035def80980">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="TestParameter" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="listOfItems" class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="orderId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dealerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dealerName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dealerAddress" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dealerContact" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="orgPrice" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="bonus" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="discount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="finalPrice" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="listOfItems" class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="503">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="240" width="100" height="20" uuid="023f299c-597f-46e6-b9bb-8330926484e4"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Bonus]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="1" y="264" width="362" height="46" uuid="c75b5fd2-6c4b-480b-91a3-9440ca3c71fa"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bonus}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="380" y="244" width="84" height="16" uuid="2560e5b8-b3f2-4962-9e4a-7890ee48eb84"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Invoice Payment]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="380" y="264" width="84" height="16" uuid="c7d9167e-2c29-41af-9a2b-d576f5d5cf33"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Discount]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="380" y="284" width="84" height="16" uuid="3ed37e4e-be08-4dd8-a751-0b788a4ebc54"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Payable Payments]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="465" y="282" width="90" height="18" uuid="6ef42f61-bd40-4db6-82e2-793c47f72ccc"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{finalPrice}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="465" y="264" width="90" height="16" uuid="62dbd5d9-18ee-49c8-a868-740087d110b1"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{discount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="465" y="244" width="90" height="16" uuid="453a26cb-3638-4bf7-9222-643d10f48207"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{orgPrice}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="1" y="233" width="555" height="1" uuid="44809847-2137-43f5-aef1-e7f4e8c76491"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="339" width="261" height="101" uuid="1a0d7088-5af7-4865-8be1-41ec5f51fb36"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.1" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.1" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.1" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.1" lineStyle="Dashed"/>
                </box>
                <text><![CDATA[Your notes here
Your notes here
Your notes here
Your notes here
Your notes here]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="210" height="25" uuid="e622555d-198b-4ccd-a4a1-c59c53304058">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="19" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Younas Traders]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="205" height="15" uuid="c226e44d-3bb5-4145-b0b3-903bf1d79fde"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Street address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="45" width="205" height="15" uuid="b96f7183-44f8-43ad-ba60-43d8fbf50b6e"/>
                <text><![CDATA[City, street, ZIP code]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="205" height="15" uuid="b8cc42fd-b569-497d-834d-7e854040ad18"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Phone number, web address, ecc.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="84" height="25" uuid="57aed2b1-4f4e-40a3-a6ad-54dae8dd4c5a">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Bill to]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="115" width="40" height="15" uuid="33274f5d-5b7e-4be2-a2ff-65d452a618ed"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="130" width="40" height="15" uuid="1d3045ed-03d6-4253-a959-aeeb491b73ca"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="40" y="115" width="140" height="15" uuid="424a926c-30f5-48ba-965e-e9c64ea93c09"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dealerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="40" y="130" width="140" height="15" uuid="b3fd9ce4-cab2-4102-882a-1f51e38fef4e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dealerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="465" y="10" width="84" height="20" uuid="bb10dbe1-0a4f-4722-9953-c163b63cf979"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="415" y="10" width="50" height="20" uuid="0f86baff-6386-4f3f-b3fe-2388707babe8"/>
                <box rightPadding="4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="415" y="30" width="50" height="20" uuid="0b3f9342-da78-4cfa-9fc5-2301c4749678"/>
                <box rightPadding="4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Invoice #]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="465" y="30" width="84" height="20" uuid="c108d3cf-4809-4862-abca-6ed67e9f6066"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{orderId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="360" y="115" width="50" height="15" uuid="235bf8b6-1e1e-49c7-b59f-7a46c30b8209"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="360" y="90" width="196" height="25" uuid="139ebe8d-25b0-411e-986c-270015400874">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contact Info]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="410" y="115" width="146" height="15" uuid="92657a77-3115-4437-9c5c-79cd3a7b8de7"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dealerAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="410" y="131" width="146" height="14" uuid="70bf5644-2451-4079-ad60-00d7462e5029"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dealerContact}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="360" y="130" width="50" height="15" uuid="665f25c2-8663-4951-b699-1ab863bdeb76"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Contact]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-10" y="84" width="556" height="1" uuid="806ce5df-1219-4876-ae0c-ca7405b1f246">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="480" width="556" height="1" uuid="210638e1-1901-4517-bef1-aad33e0bf0d2"/>
            </break>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="3" y="180" width="552" height="40" uuid="e328f355-34f5-4f03-b487-f3976e3363f0"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfItems})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{listOfItems}]]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="71"/>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

**Sub Report**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.11.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.11.0-0c4056ccaa4d25a5a8c45672d2f764ea3498bebb  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ItemsDetail" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="017e107d-3aa8-4a1e-8830-154cd4e30b51">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="itemNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="itemName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="quantity" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="unit" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="40" height="26" uuid="a41d735b-427a-407f-ab30-823815930dbc">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="f0337735-db21-4453-bf38-5b2818b709bd"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sr No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="40" y="10" width="80" height="26" uuid="2932eb5f-61e2-4ec9-a398-06110d34db6f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="25158f69-d1fc-4a93-a0c0-a631797fcf41"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Item No]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="120" y="10" width="270" height="26" uuid="07ca2115-2395-4a57-b1b0-49bce35d7ae9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="1b19a0c1-1fe2-4816-a6f4-d6537129a33d"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Item Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="10" width="80" height="26" uuid="ae2b917d-3dd1-4543-89d6-617847e668c6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="93a5ea62-c6bc-4420-8220-beb00fa064c8"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Quantity]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="470" y="10" width="85" height="26" uuid="48e2794a-6a19-4012-b023-31366dc43306">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="dde337f4-f033-42bb-8533-654ccdea99d0"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Unit]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="40" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="21fd205d-e27c-41db-89d3-bc2e34001baf">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="25158f69-d1fc-4a93-a0c0-a631797fcf41"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{itemNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="270" height="20" uuid="c389cf68-9eb4-4de4-a38a-2d0a184267a7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="1b19a0c1-1fe2-4816-a6f4-d6537129a33d"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{itemName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="390" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="eec1bb74-3a3b-4e3e-a946-f192c17129c2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="93a5ea62-c6bc-4420-8220-beb00fa064c8"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="470" y="0" width="85" height="20" uuid="060897c5-c6bc-41db-b4bb-74f9b0930522">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="dde337f4-f033-42bb-8533-654ccdea99d0"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{unit}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="20" uuid="f5e5a0a4-ed77-4744-8aac-dd546115e273"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

`subreportExpression` element value represents the compiled sub report (.jasper) file name (file path with file name). it support to values from following classes,

- java.lang.String (default)
- java.io.File
- java.io.InputStream
- java.net.URL
- JasperReport

in your case, declared a parameter as `listOfItems` with calss type `java.util.ArrayList` and it passed to `subreportExpression`. but `java.util.ArrayList` class type is not supported to `subreportExpression`

try with one of the following methods,

1. pass sub report name and sub report file path directly to `subreportExpression`.

   ```
   <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Your Sub Report File Path/ItemsDetail.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>  // sub report name is a ItemaDetail
   ```
2. declared a parameter with class type `java.lang.String` then, it pass to `subreportExpression`.

   ```
   <parameter name="SUB_REPORT_FILE" class="java.lang.String"/>

   <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUB_REPORT_FILE}]]></subreportExpression>
   ```

   in run time you should pass the sub report file name to `SUB_REPORT_FILE` parameter in java application as given below,

   ```
   HashMap<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   parameterMap.put("SUB_REPORT_FILE", "Your Sub Report File Path/ItemsDetail.jasper");
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("Your Master Report File Path/Invoice.jasper", parameterMap, YOUR_JRBeanCollectionDataSource);  // master report name is a Invoice
   ```

   or,
   pass `SUB_REPORT_FILE` parameter with sub report file name to `subreportExpression` and set the sub report file path only at run time

   in master report (Invoice.jrxml),

   ```
   <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUB_REPORT_FILE}+"/ItemsDetail.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
   ```

   in java application,

   ```
   HashMap<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   parameterMap.put("SUB_REPORT_FILE", "Your Sub Report File Path");  // pass the sub report file path only
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("Your Master 
   Report File Path/Invoice.jasper", parameterMap, YOUR_JRBeanCollectionDataSource);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There's an additional closing ] in the XML fragment below:

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{listOfItems}]]]></subreportExpression>
```

Remove it to fix the error:

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{listOfItems}]]></subreportExpression>
```